# Invoke-Expression not working

Tags: powershell-2.0, invoke-command

Can anyone help me why my artifacts are not passing to my script file?

`caller.ps1`:

```bsh
$FilePath = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\hashtest\generate-artifact-report.ps1"
$outputPath = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\hashtest\test.html";
$buildNumber=19;
$versionNumber ="2.3.7";

$artifacts = @()
$artifacts += @{Name="Test"; ExeLink="https://google.com"; MsiLink="https://google.com";}
$artifacts += @{Name="Test Stagning"; ExeLink="https://google.com"; MsiLink="https://google.com";}
$artifacts += @{Name="Test Stagning"; ExeLink="https://google.com"; MsiLink="https://google.com";}

$temp = [string]::Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", $GenerateArtifcateReportScript, $outputPath, $buildNumber, $versionNumber, $artifacts)
Invoke-Expression($temp)
```

`generate-artifact-report.ps1`:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position =0)]
    [string]$outputPath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position =1)]
    [string]$buildNumber,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position =2)]
    [string]$versionNumber,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position =3)]
    [System.Object[]]$artifacts
)

$Style = "
<style>
    .brandCol { width:250px; font-weight:bold; padding:10px; }
    .fileCol { width:250px; text-align:center; }
</style>
"

$BrandTable = "
<h1>WorkSmart Artifact Download Links</h1>
<div style='font-size:20px; padding:10px;'>
    <strong>Build Number :</strong> $buildNumber<br />
    <strong>Version :</strong> $versionNumber<br />
</div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='brandCol'>Brands</td>
            <td class='brandCol fileCol'>MSI</td>
            <td class='brandCol fileCol'>EXE (With Prerequisite)</td>
        </tr>";

foreach ($artifact in $artifacts) {
    $name = $artifact.Name;
    $exeLink = $artifact.ExeLink;
    $msiLink = $artifact.MsiLink;

    $BrandTable = $BrandTable + "
    <tr>
        <td class='brandCol'>$name</td>
        <td class='fileCol'><a href='$msiLink'>Download</a></td>
        <td class='fileCol'><a href='$exeLink'>Download</a></td>
    </tr>";
}

$BrandTable = $BrandTable + "</tbody>
    </table>
";

#Save the HTML Web Page
ConvertTo-Html -Head $Style -PreContent $BrandTable | Out-File $outputPath
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[string]::Format(...)` call mangles your array of hashtables into the string representation of the array. Which is the string `System.Object[]`. If you output the variable `$temp` you'll see that you're getting

```
 C:\Users\test\Desktop\hashtest\test.html 19 2.3.7 System.Object[]
```

The script path is missing because you assign it to a variable `$FilePath`, but use a variable `$GenerateArtifcateReportScript` in `[string]::Format()`.

Besides, you don't want to use `Invoke-Expression` anyway. It's almost always the wrong tool for the job. Use the [call operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) (`&`) instead:

```
& $FilePath $outputPath $buildNumber $versionNumber $artifacts
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling Invoke-Expression which takes a string, it can't handle passing complex objects.

You can try invoking it as a function and . source your script (and name the function in it.

Like this

```
. generate-artifact-report.ps1
Generate-ArtifactReport $outputpath $buildnumber $versionnumbee $artifacts # name the function inside the ps1 file
```